# Android property animation: how to increase view height?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, objectanimator, viewpropertyanimator

How to increase the view height using Property Animations in Android?

```
ObjectAnimator a = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewToIncreaseHeight, "translationY", -100);
a.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
a.setDuration(1000);
a.start();
```

The translationY actually moves the view not increase the height. How can I increase the height of the view?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(viewToIncreaseHeight.getMeasuredHeight(), -100);
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = viewToIncreaseHeight.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = val;
        viewToIncreaseHeight.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
});
anim.setDuration(DURATION);
anim.start();
```

Comment: scale increases the height both ways. i want to increase the height to one direction.

Comment: use `ValueAnimator` instead

Comment: yes, thats what I just did before your answer :-p, but i'll accept it. thanks

Comment: and who is the viewGroup, from which view are you getting it from?

Comment: Very slow method as changing the view will be calculated at each frame.

Comment: can we change the pivot?

Comment: why start from measuredHeight? actual height would make more sense to me. measuredHeight could be significantly bigger, in which case, the part animating from measuredHeight to height would be doing nothing.

Comment: Best solution! Thank you

Comment: Hello @g.revolution, could you please share me your code what increase the height to one direction. I did try the above code but it's changing both ways. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 19):

You can use [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html), which can save you some lines of code :

```
yourView.animate()
   .scaleY(-100f)
   .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
   .setDuration(1000);
```

that should be all you need, be sure to check the documentation and all available methods for [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html).

Comment: Don't forget the closing brackets on that AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator instance creation

Comment: `scale` will grow the `view` in both directions, and stretch its child views _(if it has any)_. The __OP__ wants to animate the `height` of the `view` only.

Comment: @Mudlabs you can simply change the pivot of the view -> `android:transformPivotY="0dp" `

Answer (score 16):

This is not a direct answer to this question. However, it may help someone.

Sometimes, we want to increase/decrease view's height because some of its child is is being added/removed (or just becoming visible/gone).

On those cases, you really can use Android default animation. As mentioned in other answers, you can set via:

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
.../>
```

Or in Java:

```
linearLayout.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
```

If you created a custom view:

```
public StickerPickerView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
        final int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
}
```

For me, it was pretty satisfactory but I just tested on latest APIs. That will automatically add a fade in/out when your view becomes visible. It will also animate the height/width of your view when same changes (like when you change the visibility of one of the child views etc).

So, I recommend to at least give a try.

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for! Sadly, doesn't work on smooth animating recycler view when adding / removing items. Throws exception: Providing a LayoutTransition into RecyclerView is not supported. Please use setItemAnimator()

Comment: if  ```android:animateLayoutChanges="true"``` didn't work in nested views, then you need to add             ```linearlayout.layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)``` to the parent layout which will be resized.

Answer (score 8):

Use this method in kotlin:

```
private fun increaseViewSize(view: View) {
    val valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(view.measuredHeight, view.measuredHeight+20)
    valueAnimator.duration = 500L
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener {
        val animatedValue = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
        val layoutParams = view.layoutParams
        layoutParams.height = animatedValue
        view.layoutParams = layoutParams
    }
    valueAnimator.start()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
fun View.animateHeightFromTo(initialHeight: Int, finalHeight: Int) {
    val animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialHeight, finalHeight)
    animator.duration = 250
    animator.addUpdateListener {
        val value = it.animatedValue as Int
        val lp = this.layoutParams
        lp.height = value
        this.layoutParams = lp
        isVisible = value != 0
    }
    animator.start()
}
```

The visibility setting was convenient for me but you may not want that

Answer (score 1):

For `kotlin` you can use this method

```
private fun increaseViewSize(view: View, increaseValue: Int) {
    val valueAnimator =
        ValueAnimator.ofInt(view.measuredHeight, view.measuredHeight + increaseValue)
    valueAnimator.duration = 500L
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener {
        val animatedValue = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
        val layoutParams = view.layoutParams
        layoutParams.height = animatedValue
        view.layoutParams = layoutParams
    }
    valueAnimator.start()
}
```

It will increase view's size as defined in parameter

based on @Minion answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to animate scrolling an item to center of the screen inside a recycleView

```
// Scrolling with animation
val valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(getWidth() / 2)
valueAnimator.duration = 250L
valueAnimator.addUpdateListener {
    val animatedValue = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
    (layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(itemToScroll, animatedValue)
}
valueAnimator.start()
// End of scrolling with animation
```

Note it is a bit similar to **UIView.animate** in Swift, but with more complication

Answer (score -2):

It's pretty straight forward as you can see below.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
.../>
```

More info below:

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout

Comment: In order for this to work you would have to add the view to the layout.

Comment: This solution animates the view's children, not the view itself.