# Android expand view animation

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I have a bottomBar that i would like to expand. I think i know how to do it with animations.

But according to [What is the difference between an Animator and an Animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220613/what-is-the-difference-between-an-animator-and-an-animation)

If i use old animations. Then the buttons would not be relocated. Only visually.

How could i achieve this with Animators.

**What i am trying to achieve**

[image]

So could someone nudge me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem.

```
    public static ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end, final View view, int duration) {
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = val;
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
    animator.setDuration(duration);
    return animator;
}
```

Credit to: [Android property animation: how to increase view height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835397/android-property-animation-how-to-increase-view-height)

Answer (score 1):

Well, that can be done with a "one-liner":

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(viewGroup);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = endValue;
view.invalidate();
```