# There is a jerk when I set visibility GONE for this button

Tags: java, android, android-animation

[image: See this image is having a jerk when I set visibility gone]

I am using android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
here I am sharing my card view layout :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvRegisteredPharmacy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivPharmacy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPharmacyName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Pharmacy Name"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <RatingBar
                        android:id="@+id/rbPharmacyRating"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:numStars="5"
                        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                        android:rating="3.5"
                        android:progressTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/colorGrey" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPharmacyInfo"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="3.5"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPharmacyAddress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Pharmacy Address, 1/2 Main St NW, Monteral, QC"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSelectPharmacy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_white"
                android:text="Select Pharmacy"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the complete layout that I've made

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.PharmacyMapActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvPharmaciesList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, I am sharing the simple code where I am setting visibility of this button :

```
if (holder.btnSelectPharmacy.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                    holder.btnSelectPharmacy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    holder.btnSelectPharmacy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I've tried many solutions so far including view animation, Object animator, Expandable layout (through library) but no luck so far!
looking forward for your suggestions.
I've a workaround for this to lift the card up but then I want to make my card expanded from upside exactly as like as in the above picture.

Comment: Can you also share the layout code of the complete screen?

Comment: If i make it invisible it will take extra space @MartinZeitler

Comment: I am not quite sure if you really need the LinearLayout around the CardView. One essential point could be to add layout_gravity="bottom" to the parent layout. That was the reason why I asked for the code of the layout for the complete screen.

Comment: let me edit the question @JulianSchweppe & yes, I am using layout gravity bottom because i need this card at the bottom of the screen

Comment: @JulianSchweppe I've editied my post as you requested for the layout

Comment: I only see two times the same layout. Can you paste the XML layout with the recyclerview within?

Comment: I am sorry @JulianSchweppe. Now, I've updated my question. please check

Comment: You can try [Yoyo library](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations). Implement the fadeOut/zoomOut anim before hiding the view. Optionally you can also [animate the view height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32835417/8043806) from initial to zero to simulate an easy exit

Answer (score 0):

While using automatic layout animation on the child node, the result will be, that the parent node just snaps to `layout_alignParentBottom` & `wrap_content` once the child node is `View.GONE`.

Combining two animations could make it less jerky. I mean, the `CardView` would need it's height animated; either synchronously or once the child node is `View.GONE`. Actually, when animating the child node to height 0dp, this would also animate the parent node's height, since it's `wrap_content`; setting a static value for the height would also prevent it from snapping alike that. Also animating to `View.INVISBLE` and then animating it's height would prevent the parent node from snapping. Sorry for not providing a ready-made solution, but explaining why it behaves alike that and how it might work is still better than no answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Martin Zeitler, I know the reason but unable to resolve it. Can you answer it programmatically?