# How to adjust size imageview based on bottomsheet behavior?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I've created an application with logo (imageview) and bottom sheet in there, when bottomsheet is up then the logo will move. But i want to make if bottomsheet up the changes not only move but the logo also change it size to be a big size, and when bottomsheet is down then the size of the logo back to the normal size, anyone can help me?

[like this design of figma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7dsc.png)

This is my code xml right now the imageview just move not resize

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
        app:layout_insetEdge="bottom">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_remove_24" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:text="Let’s Get \nStarted"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="48sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:letterSpacing="0.015"
                android:text="Share your story here and get inspiration, \nmotivation, passion, and new friends."
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_join"
                android:layout_width="335dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_rounded"
                android:text="Join Now"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:text="Already have an account? "
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn_join"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_join" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Login"

                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="219dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
          app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/love"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:src="@drawable/love"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.319" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Track the event when bottomsheet is accessed and animate the view size for the image accordingly.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32835417/14700539), You can get help with animating the view size.